# 'Wrong major API version for gpuarray:', -9997, 'Make sure Theano and libgpuarray/pygpu are in sync.'

Tags: gpu, opencl, theano, amd-gpu

```
ERROR (theano.sandbox.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/mesayantan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>

    init_dev(config.device)
  File "/home/mesayantan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 46, in init_dev

    "Make sure Theano and libgpuarray/pygpu "
RuntimeError: ('Wrong major API version for gpuarray:', -9997, 'Make sure Theano and libgpuarray/pygpu are in sync.')

[Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float32, vector)>)]
Looping 1000 times took 26.248654 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178029  1.61879337  1.52278066 ...,  2.20771813  2.29967761
  1.62323284]
Used the cpu
```

Comment: The problem is solved by installing the developer version of theano.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved by installing the developer version of theano.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sayantan Ghosh.

I used developer version Theano in Anaconda using 

`git clone https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
cd Theano
pip install -e .`

One more step was specific Pygpu library by 
`conda install -c mila-udem pygpu`

After then I have to put command line in Terminal `export THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=cuda,floatX=float32` to solve Old Backend GPU error.

For your reference, my environment, Python 3.6, Cuda 9, Cudnn 7